# Probability distribution of phase-space reconstructions

Tags: probability, statistics, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

I am unable to find resources regarding the probability density and distribution of non-linear chaotic systems in phase space.

For example, if a discrete one-dimensional system, say the logistic map, is embedded with an embedding dimension $M > 2d+1$, will the probability density function of the system having the embedding dimension $M$ change? According to  [the Wikipedia article on the logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), the distribution of values is the beta distribution (for $r=4$). If the Logistic map is embedded with the Takens delay method with $M=5$, will the prbability density function in the 5-dimensional embedding space remain beta-distributed? Or will it change? If it changes, then how to determine the probability density function in the embedded phase space?

Comment: can you clarify the phrase "*discrete one dimensional system of dimension $d$ is embedded in $M>2d+1$*"?

Comment: ahh is this about the *delay method* to embed a non-linear system in higher dimension for analysis?

Comment: @NikosM.: Absolutely. I don't know any information about the density functions in phase space of a time series that has been reconstructed by Takens delay embedding theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I found it very difficult to understand your question, but here is an attempt at answering it:</sup>

The whole point of embedding is to uncover the phase-space structure or, with other words, something that is topologically equivalent to the attractor. For any interesting system, this is not describable by your usual distributions (and also it is usually not described in terms of distributions). In particular, no lower-dimensional slice through this distribution corresponds to the distribution for the respective lower $M$.

In the example of the logistic map with $r=4$ and $M=2$ and a delay $τ=1$, the attractor is almost the whole parabola $4·x·(1-x)$. Thus your distribution is $0$ for all points not on this parabola. In particular, any one-dimensional slice of this distribution is non-zero for at most two points (and thus fundamentally different from a beta distribution).

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience to go through my problem. Based on your answer, please correct me if wrong. You mean to say that the probability distribution changes in the delay embedded space. If so, then how does one know or derive the distribution & the density in phase space?Your reason as to why the distribution must change is understood.But my question is how to determine the statistics like mean, variance, pdf in phase space?I had asked this question before in stats.exchange a long time ago which went unanswered since they said that it is related to physics due to the embedding.

Comment: @SKM: I do not think that there is a general way to calculate statistical moments or something similar for slices of a Takens embedding. Just consider the slices of the parabola you get for the logistic map. Their variance obviously strongly varies depending on how you slice. In general, those phase-space embeddings can be very complex structures (strange attractors are fractals) and thus I would find it very surprising if there were an easy way to do compute statistical moments for slices through them.

Comment: Ok, so what if we want to estimate parameters of the system for example, Lorenz system after phase space embedding? In order to do so, we must have the probability density function of the reconstructed time series in phase space. Do you suggest that we cannot perform any estimation in phase space?

Comment: @SKM: If you so wish, what the phase-space embedding gives you, **is** this probability density function and you can straightforwardly compute whatever you want for it. But I would not know of any way to get to the statistical moments or similar without it. Moreover, given the complicated nature of most attractors, statistical moments won’t do a good job at describing it.

Comment: Just to confirm if we are on the same page:(A) So, probability density function in attractor dimension (say, beta pdf of logistic map) $\neq$ pdf on embedded space (will not remain beta distributed anymore); (B) You have not yet told whether there is any technique to derive the pdf in embedded space and if there is not then what is the most common pdf chosen.

Comment: B) Apart from phase-space-embedding some data, I do not think there is any technique. I do not see any point in assuming some PDF for the phase-space embedding. I would not even know why you need such a distribution in the first place.